Reference request: books on convex analysis / geometry
I am interested in convex geometry and analysis, especially in its connections with high dimensional probability theory.
I was reading the book by Pisier, The volume of convex bodies and Banach space geometry, in Cambridge University Press (1989).
I really enjoyed this book and its perspective, and am hoping to find a text that
(a) presents some more recent developments and,
(b) if possible, has some exercises.
Let me know your suggestions.
